# How to create list, who can contains function

Tags: c++, list

How to create list, who can contains function with signature `int foo(int x);`, functors with defined `int operator()(int x);` and functors from `std::bind1st`.

Comment: Um.. there is a `bind1st` in `std`? I really need to start paying more attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `std::list<std::function<int(int)>>`